# I want to insert a value into my custom database table in magento.. how do i do it with Magnento ORM without using direct query?

Tags: php, magento, orm

I want to insert a value into my custom database table in magento.. how do i do it with Magento ORM without using a SQL query?

Could someone pleas give me a hand on this?

Thanks a lot in advance.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm) will walk you through the basics of Magento's ORM system. A similar article exists on the Magento [knowledge base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics) and a follow-on article on [using EAV](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value).

If you have specific queries after you've read and implemented those patterns, ask here again.

Comment: Ok thanks.. and also i am reading data from db using ORM like    $select = $read->select()
      ->from($tableName,array("ManufacturerID", "Model"))
      ->where("Value1 like '%".$queryText."%'");  how do i add paging (limit 0,10 like concept) along with this ORM concept?

Comment: To be fair, if you are constructing SQL manually, you are not using ORM at all. To use ORM, you would be interfacing with an object (Product, Customer, Category, etc).

Comment: As Joseph says, the code that you are writing is not ORM, it's one tiny step away from writing raw SQL.  Read the articles in my answer and rewrite your app using the ORM to get and set the data.  You'll find that it actually saves you a HUGE amount of effort in looking up the specifics of the complex data structure once you use the Models correctly.

Comment: Thank you verymuch Jonathan and Joseph, you guys really opened up my eyes on this ORM thing......!!!! Thanks a lot..!